# Pass array of values for key of JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I don't think what am asking is possible without using a loop but I would like to confirm to see if anyone has tried something like it.

I currently am doing a request builder and mapping a bunch of data - so I tried doing the following which of course doesn't work:

```
let value = "TestVal"
let ObjAgg = {
  "Address": "",
  "Address1": ""
};
let currentKeys = Object.keys(ObjAgg)
let chunkArray = lodash.chunk(currentKeys, 1)
ObjAgg[chunkArray] = value;
```

My idea is I can just pass in the keys via the chunkArray var which will separate out the values into seperate arrays using lodash to something like this `[Address][Address1]` and know exactly where am inserting said value without having to loop.

I have tried a couple of things and of course I don't think this will work - but I am curious to see if it can be done.

The output would be something like this:

```
{
  "Address": {
    "Address1": "TestVal"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will be good if you can give an example.

Comment: And a desired output

Comment: Are you asking if you have a nested object and a key, can you reach the value of key without looping every object in main object?

Comment: I have updated the example in the question to have more information - in short @acbay yes but I want to set the value at the destination of the chunk array, I was curious as to if I knew the key values could I pass them somehow to the object somehow rather than map through the object. I would usually map but I was wondering if this was even possible to do without it.